# Group By Linq Using Auto Mapper c#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Hope you all are doing well!

I am working on one project inside which I have 2 models

```
// Model - I
public class Model_1
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

//Model - II
public class Model_2
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public IList<Model_1> Model_1 {get;set;}
}
```

Can anyone write a linq query in order to group by Model_1. I have written a query but it says something like

```
Create using CreateMap<IGrouping`2, GetModel2Dto>.
```

Early response is appreciated.

My Query:

```
var groupByResult= from model_2 in _context.Model_2
                        group model_2 by model_2.model_1 into newGroup
                        orderby newGroup.Key
                        select newGroup;
```

Comment: `Model2` has a _collection_ of `Model1`. How do you expect that to group?

Comment: Automapper for simple mapping, not for business logic. Don't make things complicated. Also grouping without aggregation has not sense.

Comment: If you want to groupby, it's better to use the linq itself. And it's better to send commands to the database(use linq to sql). Can you get the output you want with this query? What is the expected output?